# Is accept() thread-safe?

Tags: c, pthreads, threadpool, sockets

I'm currently writing a simple webserver in C for a course I'm doing. One requirement is for us to implement a thread pool to handle connections using pthreads.

I know how I would go about doing this roughly(calling accept in a main thread and passing the file descriptor to a freee thread), however my friend suggested an alternate method than the one I had in mind: creating all my threads up front, and getting them all to loop forever on a call to accept. The idea being that accept will block all the idle threads and when a connection comes in, only giving the file descriptor to one. Then when a given thread is done with a connection it loops back around and blocks on a call to accept again. Using the call to accept() as a semaphore essentially. This would simplify the implementation quite a bit he figures, as you wouldn't need to keep track of which threads are busy and which are ready for a connection. It would also be lower latency in theory, as the thread can immediately start executing.

My question is, is this safe? I'm planning to implement it and try it out, but I'm not ready yet and I'm quite curious to know the answer. I've searched on google and here on stackoverflow, but couldn't find anyone doing it this way. Is accept thread safe? I assume there will be more overhead with this approach as you are running all your threads all the time, are the two approaches simply a simple memory/latency tradeoff?

Edit: I'm unsure if this should be community wiki, apologies if it should be, I can't find the button :P

Comment: Be a bit careful here, the POSIX definition of "thread-safe" means that you can call the function concurrently from different threads. It doesn't imply that you necessarily can call the function concurrently *mutating the same data* with predictable results or even defined behavior. `strcpy` is thread-safe, but it won't take any kind of lock. In POSIX, "not thread safe" means *very* unsafe. By the POSIX definition, `accept()` is thread-safe (ie not on the list here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_09.html), but you need more than that.

Comment: @Steve: While that's a valid warning for interfaces to which you pass pointers, it doesn't apply to file descriptors/sockets. OP's usage is perfectly safe.

Comment: @R..: I thought it probably was safe, but where does POSIX explain/define that? Is there a specific term for it beyond "thread-safe"?

Comment: @Steve: It goes along with open file descriptions (to which file descriptors refer) being a shared resource accessible by many processes, but I can't find the text...

Comment: @SteveJessop The word is 'atomic'.

Comment: @EJP: you'd think, wouldn't you? But for example opengroup doesn't define "atomic" in the place it defines "thread-safe": http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html . I don't have access to the IEEE publication of the POSIX standard to check properly.

Comment: @Rick All system calls are atomic on every operating system I have ever used since 1971.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne All system calls are atomic? Shouldn't we say **thread-safe**? And not all system calls are thread safe. Also I think thead-safe and atomic are  two different but related terms. [Difference between Atomic Operation and Thread Safety?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/178900/304837)

Comment: @Rick: System calls should always be thread-safe. The kernel has to have that level of safety to operate correctly. This is because all processes share the same kernel, and when inside the kernel, the execution of the system call from two separate processes look like two threads of execution in the kernel. POSIX does not define system calls, only the behaviors of the APIs. If an API gets implemented as a system call in a particular implementation, then it needs to be made thread-safe.

Comment: @jxh No wonder when I tried to check some posix thread unsafe function with e.g `man asctime`, the manpage shows the results in section 3 (`CTIME(3)`), which belongs to the **Library calls** section, not the system call section. You helped me out again. :P. Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes.  This is a common way to design multithreaded servers and accepted design practice.

You can also `fork` several times and have the child processes call `accept`, this will allow you to do multithreading without needing a threads library.  Older servers do this.

Comment: Hey @Dietrich, could you give some references about that? I couldn't find any related authoritative materials . Check my question here  [Is there any authoritative place that says multi processes or threads accepting a listening socket is an atomic operation?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/605832/is-there-any-authoritative-place-that-says-multi-processes-or-threads-accepting) . Thank you

Comment: @Rick - it’s a system call. It’s not a library function. There is no reasonable way for accept() to be unsafe. If it were unsafe, the kernel itself would be unsafe. You can fund a list of MT safe functions if you like. I am not going to do that, because I already know it is on that list. This is the way programs have been splitting work since before pthreads existed.

Comment: @Rick - see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html - accept is listed as async signal safe

Comment: In some ways I get the point now. thread-safe would be the property that meets the behaviour. I was thinking thread-safe has to be threads within same process. But now I think there aren't much differences between threads within same process or threads between different processes. In some ways they are the same. So the concept of thread-safety can be applied to both scenarios.

Comment: And I think atomic and thread safe are 2 different but related terms. Thread safe would be the appropriate term to meet this scenario, not atomic.  [Difference between Atomic Operation and Thread Safety?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/178900/304837).

Comment: That question isn’t relevant because it is talking specifically about lockless atomic primitives. I think the problem is that if you want to read the relevant standards, there’s a certain background that you are expected to have. These standards also stop short of giving formal semantics, you’re expected to be able to make certain intuitive leaps or have a good grasp of the bigger picture—if you want a deeper understanding, find a good operating systems book. There’s just too much material to cover to understand the standard, far too much to fit into a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: I’m not trying to dodge the question—it’s good that you’re looking for authoritative sources, but I think this path may be a bit of a shortcut and you may be much more satisfied and happy by taking the “long road” through an operating systems textbook. It’s clear that you’re interested in the subject and you’re taking an analytical approach to the subject, and a good textbook will have the clarity, precision, and depth that I don’t have.

Comment: Thank you for you sincere advice. Yes, I am definitely willing to take the "long road". It is just sometimes I don't know what I am missing until someone told me. Btw, would you like to recommend some good books you've read related to this field(operating system?)? I will collect them and read later.

Answer (score 3):

Since this has been bountied, asking for references:

Yes, `accept()` is thread-safe, as POSIX defines that term.

The relevant reference would be [section 2.9.1 of POSIX.1](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_01), the current version of which says:

> All functions defined by this volume of POSIX.1-2017 shall be
> thread-safe, except that the following functions need not be
> thread-safe.
>
> [a list that does not include `accept()`]

For completeness, POSIX *does* define `accept()`: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/accept.html, so as a POSIX function that does not appear on the list of exceptions, POSIX specifies that it is thread-safe.

Comment: In some ways I get the point now. **thread-safe** would be the property that meets the behaviour. I was thinking **thread-safe** has to be **threads within same process**. But now I think there aren't much differences between threads within same process or threads between different processes. In some ways they are the same. So the concept of **thread-safety** can be applied to both scenarios.

Comment: @Rick, threads within the same process share the state of the process.  This makes thread safety with respect to threads belonging to the same process a strictly stronger property than thread safety with respect to threads of different processes.  In most regards, process isolation makes cross-process thread safety a non-issue.

Answer (score 2):

In comments, @Rick (the bounty offerer) says:

> <sub>In some ways I get the point now. thread-safe would be the property that meets the behaviour. I was thinking thread-safe has to be threads within same process. But now I think there aren't much differences between threads within same process or threads between different processes. In some ways they are the same. So the concept of thread-safety can be applied to both scenarios.</sub>

The POSIX definitions regarding thread-safety do indeed refer to threads in the same process (see: [§2.9](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09)).

If you are asking about what happens after `fork()`, and if it is safe for the parent and child to concurrently call into `accept()`, we note first that POSIX defines a system resource known as a [connection indication queue](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_10_13). Then we note that the child of [`fork()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) gets a copy of the parent's descriptors, and therefore the child and parent will access the same connection indication queue (just as a duplicate file descriptor to a text file would be accessing the same file).

The definition of what `accept()` does for each process (child and parent) is the same at that point.

Comment: Ah. I know that connection indication queue. It's what `backlog` in `int listen(int sockfd, int backlog)` refers to.

Comment: Also, thank you for clearing some of my doubts about parent and child concurrently call into `accept()`. I just read the §2.9 section. And yes, thread-safety is defined as threads in the same process. And my idea about "thread-safety between different processes" is  heading the wrong direction. The problem is more likely related to multiple threads or processes concurrently access the connection indication queue system-wide resource you mention.

Comment: @Rick: Right, `listen()` will associate a connection indication queue to a socket. So, if a socket gets duplicated (either with `dup()` or copied to a child via `fork()`) the sockets refer to the same connection indication queue.

Comment: @Rick: The API definitions give the behavior of the call from the process. Each process is supposed to see the same behavior as specified. So `accept()` from both a child and parent process should just work. The OP was asking about from multiple threads in the same process, and that is also defined to work, since `accept()` is thread-safe.

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic. You said *"The API definitions give the behavior of the call **from the process**. Each process is supposed to see the same behavior **as specified**."* I don't understand what you are exactly refer to here, because when I searched `man 2 accept` with keyword `process`, I don't find anything related or useful.

Comment: @Rick: The standard defines what a process is. Where else would code execute from?

Answer (score 2):

Applications link against the `libc` implementation on a system in order to call `accept()` and other socket-related functions (`#include <sys/socket.h>`). You want to read its documentation.

The most common implementation of `libc` on Linux comes from GNU (or maybe `bionic` from Google on Android), it is called `glibc` and it is very likely what you are (will be) using. As stated in [`accept` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Accepting-Connections.html) for `glibc`:

> Function: int accept (int socket, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *length_ptr)
>
> Preliminary: | MT-Safe | AS-Safe | AC-Safe fd | [See POSIX Safety Concepts.](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/POSIX-Safety-Concepts.html)

As explained in *POSIX Safety concepts*, the *Preliminary* section enumerates properties which:

> are assessed according to the criteria set forth in the POSIX standard for such safety contexts as Thread-, Async-Signal- and Async-Cancel- -Safety.

And an explanation of such concepts follow (also, check ["Thread Safety" on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) for different approaches to achieve *thread safety*). `accept` is declared as **MT-Safe**, according to doc:

> MT-Safe or Thread-Safe functions are safe to call in the presence of other threads. MT, in MT-Safe, stands for Multi Thread.
>
> Being MT-Safe does not imply a function is atomic, nor that it uses any of the memory synchronization mechanisms POSIX exposes to users. It is even possible that calling MT-Safe functions in sequence does not yield an MT-Safe combination. For example, having a thread call two MT-Safe functions one right after the other does not guarantee behavior equivalent to atomic execution of a combination of both functions, since concurrent calls in other threads may interfere in a destructive way.
>
> Whole-program optimizations that could inline functions across library interfaces may expose unsafe reordering, and so performing inlining across the GNU C Library interface is not recommended. The documented MT-Safety status is not guaranteed under whole-program optimization. However, functions defined in user-visible headers are designed to be safe for inlining.

The fact that `glibc`'s `accept` implementation just redirect to the kernel system call, makes this description a useful one also for other `libc` implementations on Linux systems (which likely just perform a redirection to the system call too).

---

On the other hand, a more general approach is to check the [`man-pages project`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/) on your system if available (the closest thing to an *official documentation* on most systems), which:

> [...] documents the Linux kernel and C library interfaces that are employed by user-space programs. With respect to the C library, the primary focus is the GNU C library (glibc), although, where known, documentation of variations on other C libraries available for Linux is also included.

By typing [`man 2 accept`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) on the command line:

> [...]
> CONFORMING TO
>
> accept(): POSIX.1-2001, POSIX.1-2008, SVr4, 4.4BSD (accept() first
> appeared in 4.2BSD).

We see that [`POSIX.1-2008`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/nframe.html) is a viable reference (check [this](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/standards.7.html) for a description of relevant standards for Linux systems). As already said in other answers, `POSIX.1` standard specifies `accept` function as (`POSIX-`)*thread safe* (as defined in *Base Definitions, section 3.399 Thread Safe*) by not listing it on *System Interfaces, section 2.9.1 Thread Safety*.

---

Finally, as `glibc` just delegates on kernel's `accept()`, the most *reputable source* is the *kernel source code* (of course). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63345712/8074683) goes through kernel code path when `accept()`ing: take a look and convince yourself that shared resources are protected by spin-locks, in particular the [socket state](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.131/source/net/ipv4/inet_connection_sock.c#L311) and the [queue](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.131/source/net/ipv4/inet_connection_sock.c#L799) of connections waiting for application `accept`ance.