# Why does Apache MPM prefork.c use a mutex to protect accept()?

Tags: c, multithreading, apache, sockets, thread-safety

I sat down and read [Apache's MPM prefork.c](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/apache/httpd/server/mpm/prefork/prefork.c) and this code is using a variable called `accept_mutex` to prevent multiple threads from calling `accept()`.  This is strange because as far as I know [`accept()` is thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124320/is-accept-thread-safe).

Is accept() thread safe?  Is this a platform compatibility issue?  If so what platform implements a non-thread-safe `accept()`?

Comment: The mutex is there to avoid the "thundering herd problem".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is explained in the [Apache performance tuning documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/perf-tuning.html), under "`accept()` Serialization - multiple sockets". In brief, under at least some operating systems, an incoming connection will wake *all* Apache processes that are waiting for incoming connections in `select()` or `poll()`, but will cause the `accept()` to fail on all but one of them. This is inefficient, so a mutex is used to ensure that only one process accepts an incoming connection at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Read the comments in the source you linked to. It seems the mutex is not really protecting the `accept` operation, but the list of listening sockets that need to be polled (note that the mutex isn't used when there's only one listening socket, at least not on non-broken systems where `accept` works properly). If this could change at runtime, then the code is probably correct. But I have a feeling they're just doing something nonsensical. This is Apache, so you shouldn't expect high-quality or even reasonable code...