# Should we use multiple acceptor sockets to accept a large number of connections?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets, tcp

As known, SO_REUSEPORT allows **multiple sockets to listen on the same IP address and port** combination, it increases requests per second by **2 to 3 times**, and reduces both latency **(~30%)** and the standard deviation for latency **(8 times)**: https://www.nginx.com/blog/socket-sharding-nginx-release-1-9-1/

> NGINX release 1.9.1 introduces a new feature that enables use of the
>   **SO_REUSEPORT** socket option, which is available in newer versions of many operating systems, including DragonFly BSD and **Linux (kernel
>   version 3.9 and later)**. This socket option allows **multiple sockets
>   to listen on the same IP address and port combination**. The kernel
>   then load balances incoming connections across the sockets.
>   ...
>
> As shown in the figure, **reuseport increases requests per second by 2
>   to 3 times, and reduces both latency** and the standard deviation for
>   latency.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**`SO_REUSEPORT` is available on most modern OS**: Linux ([kernel >= 3.9](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.9) since [29 Apr 2013](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/releases/tag/v3.9)), Free/Open/NetBSD, MacOS, iOS/watchOS/tvOS, [IBM AIX 7.2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.commtrf2/getsockopt.htm), [Oracle Solaris 11.1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29044/tcp-7p.html), Windows (is only `SO_REUSEPORT` that behaves as 2 flags together `SO_REUSEPORT`+`SO_REUSEADDR` in BSD), and may be on [Android](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/73a5a3b/ndk/platforms/android-20/arch-mips64/include/asm/socket.h#32) :   https://stackoverflow.com/a/14388707/1558037

> Linux >= 3.9
>
> 2. Additionally the kernel performs some "special magic" for `SO_REUSEPORT` sockets that isn't found in other operating systems:
>      For UDP sockets, it tries to distribute datagrams evenly, for **TCP
>      listening sockets, it tries to distribute incoming connect requests**
>      (those accepted by calling `accept()`)  evenly across all the sockets
>      that share the same address and port combination. Thus **an application
>      can easily open the same port in multiple child processes and then use
>      `SO_REUSEPORT` to get a very inexpensive load balancing**.

---

Also known, to avoid locks of spin-lock and achive high performance there shouldn't be sockets which read more than 1 thread. I.e. each thread should processes its own sockets for read/write.

- `accept()` is thread-safe function for the same socket descriptor, so it should be guarded by lock - **so lock contention reduces performance**: http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.programmer/2007-06/msg00246.html

> POSIX.1-2001/SUSv3 **requires accept(), bind(), connect(), listen(),
>   socket(), send(), recv(), etc. to be thread-safe functions.** It's
>   possible that there are some ambiguities in the standard regarding
>   their interaction with threads, but the intention is that their
>   behaviour in multithreaded programs is governed by the standard.

- If we use the same one socket from many threads, then performance will be low because socket defended by lock for thread-safe accessing from many threads: https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-to-receive-a-million-packets/

> The receiving performance is down compared to a single threaded
>   program. That's **caused by a lock contention on the UDP receive buffer**
>   side. Since both threads are using the same socket descriptor, they
>   spend a disproportionate amount of time fighting for a lock around the
>   UDP receive buffer. This paper describes the problem in more detail.

- More details about spin-lock when  the  application  tries  to  read data  from  the  socket - "Analysis of Linux UDP Sockets Concurrent Performance": http://www.jcc2014.ucm.cl/jornadas/WORKSHOP/WSDP%202014/WSDP-4.pdf

> V.  K ERNEL ISOLATION
>
> ....
>
> From  the  other  side,  **when  the  application  tries  to  read data 
>   from  the  socket**,  it  executes  a  similar  process,  which 
>   isdescribed below and represented in Figure 3 from right to left:
>
> 1) Dequeue  one  or  more  packets  from  the  receive  queue, **using the
>   corresponding spinlock** (green one).
>
> 2)  Copy the information to user-space memory.
>
> 3)  Release the memory used by the packet. This
>   potentiallychanges the state of the socket, so two ways of locking the
>   socket  can  occur:  fast  and  slow.  In  both  cases,  the packet is
>   unlinked from the socket, Memory Accounting statistics are updated and
>   socket is released according to the locking path taken.

I.e. when many threads are accessing the same socket, performance degrades due to waiting on one spin-lock.

---

We have 2 x Xeon 32 HT-Cores server with 64 total HT-cores, and two 10 Gbit Ethernet cards, and Linux (kernel 3.9).

We use RFS and XPS - i.e. for the same connection TCP/IP-stack processed (kernel-space) on the same CPU-Core as an application thread (user-space).

There are at least 3 ways to accept connections to processes it at many threads:

- Use **one acceptor socket shared between many threads**, and each thread accept connections and processes it
- Use **one acceptor socket in 1 thread**, and this thread push received socket descriptors of connections to other thread-workers by using thread-safe queue
- Use **many acceptor sockets** which listen the same `ip:port`, 1 individual acceptor socket **in each thread**, and the thread that receives the connection then processes it (recv/send)

What is the more efficient way, If we accept a lot of new TCP-connections?

Answer (score 11):

Having had to handle such an occasion in production, here's a good way to approach this problem:

First, setup a single thread to handle all incoming connections. Modify the affinity map so that this thread has a dedicated core that no other threads in your application (or even your entire system) will try to access. [You can also modify your boot scripts so that certain cores are never automatically assigned to an execution unit unless that specific core is explicitly requested (i.e. `isolcpus` kernel boot parameters).](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208538/telling-linux-kernel-not-to-use-certain-cpus)

Mark that core as un-used, [and then explicitly request it in your code for the "listen to socket" thread via `cpuset`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407786/how-to-set-cpu-affinity-of-a-particular-pthread)

Next, setup a queue (ideally, a priority queue) that prioritizes write operations [(i.e. "the second readers-writers problem).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem) Now, setup however many worker threads as you see reasonable.

At this point, the goal of the "incoming connections" thread should be to:

- `accept()` incoming connections.
- Pass these connection file descriptors (FDs) off to your writer-prioritized queue structure as quickly as possible.
- Go back to its `accept()` state as quickly as possible.

This will allow you to delegate incoming connections as quickly as possible. Your worker threads can grab items from the shared queue as they arrive. It might also be worth having a second, high-priority thread that grabs data from this queue, and moves it to a secondary queue, saving the "listen to socket" thread from having to spend extra cycles delegating client FDs.

This would also prevent the "listen to socket" thread and the worker threads from ever having to access the same queue concurrently, which would save you from worst-case scenarios like a slow worker thread locking the queue when the "listen to socket" thread wants to drop data in it. i.e.

```
Incoming client connections

 ||
 || Listener thread - accept() connection.
 \/

Listener/Helper queue

 ||
 || Helper thread
 \/

Shared Worker queue

 ||
 || Worker thread #n
 \/

Worker-specific memory space. read() from client.
```

As for your other two proposed options:

> Use one acceptor socket shared between many threads, and each thread
>   accept connections and processes it.

Messy. The threads will have to somehow take turns issuing the `accept()` call, and there won't be any benefit to doing this. You'll also have some additional sequencing logic to handle which thread's "turn" is up.

> Use many acceptor sockets which listen the same ip:port, 1 individual
>   acceptor socket in each thread, and the thread that receives the
>   connection then processes it (recv/send)

[Not the most portable option. I'd avoid it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388706/socket-options-so-reuseaddr-and-so-reuseport-how-do-they-differ-do-they-mean-t) Also, you'll potentially need to make your server process use multi-process (i.e. `fork()`) as opposed to multi-threaded, depending on OS, kernel version, etc.

Comment: I've had success using pipes instead of queues to pass fixed-size data such as pointers or `int` values, like a file descriptor for an open socket. In this case, `write( pipeFDs[ 0 ], &acceptedConnFD, sizeof( acceptedConnFD ) );` puts the accepted connection's file descriptor value into the pipe. As long as `read( pipeFDs[ 1 ], &newConnValue, sizeof( newConnValue ) );` will never return a partial result, multiple threads can read values from the pipe just like a more complex queue.  Depending on the system and the implementation, a pipe can be faster than a queue and the code is really simple.

Comment: @DevNull Thank you! But why `SO_REUSEPORT` isn't the most portable option? And what problems with fork()? `SO_REUSEPORT` is available on most modern OS: **Linux (kernel>=3.9), Free/Open/NetBSD, MacOS,iOS/watchOS/tvOS, Windows** (is only SO_REUSEPORT that behaves as 2 flags together SO_REUSEPORT+SO_REUSEADDR in BSD) as said by your link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14388707/1558037 Also on **Oracle Solaris 11.1**: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29044/tcp-7p.html And also on **IBM AIX 7.2**: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.commtrf2/getsockopt.htm

Comment: @Alex Kernel 3.9 was only released about 4 years ago. A lot of long term support distros (i.e. CentOS) are behind this, making it not as portable as one would hope if he/she has to support a lot of distros. As for `fork()`, nothing wrong with using `fork()` plus pipes. I just find multithreading to be much easier to manage than multiprocess programming.

Comment: `cpuset` isn't the most portable option... it also raises the question of persistent connections vs. new connections. Dedicating a whole core for `accept` makes little sense if the bulk of the work is related to processing persistent connections events. For example, HTTP/1.1 might require a lot of `accept` calls, but HTTP/2 and Websockets are a whole different ball game.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have two 10Gbps network connection and assuming a 500byte average frame size (which is very conservative for a server without interactive use), you'll have around 2Mpackets per second per network card (I don't believe you have more than this) and this means processing 4 packets per microsec.  This is a very slow latency for a cpu like the one described in your configuration.   On these premises, I's ensure that your bottleneck will be in the network (and the switches you connect to) than in the spinlock on each socket (it takes some cpu cycles to resolve on a spinlock, and this is far beyond the limit imposed by the network).  Either, I'd dedicate a thread or two (one for reading and other for writing) maximum on each network card, and don't think much more in the socket locking features, anyway.  Most probable is your bottleneck is in the application software you have in the backend of this configuration.

Even in the case you run into trouble, perhaps it would be better to do some modifications to the kernel sofware than adding up more and more processors or thinking on distributing the spinlocks into different sockets.  Or even better, to add more network cards to aleviate the bottleneck.

Answer (score -7):

> Use many acceptor sockets which listen the same ip:port, 1 individual acceptor socket in each thread, and the thread that receives the connection then processes it (recv/send)

This is impossible in TCP. Forget it.

Do what everybody else does. One accepting thread, which starts a new thread per accepted socket, or despatches them to a thread pool.

Comment: But this is used in Ngnix: **multiple sockets to listen on the same IP address and port**: https://www.nginx.com/blog/socket-sharding-nginx-release-1-9-1/  There said: it is possible to use accept (for TCP) in many threads and this is a common way to design multithreaded servers and accepted design practice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124320/is-accept-thread-safe  **Question:** ...  creating all my **threads** up front, and getting them **all to loop forever on a call to accept.** ...  **Answer:** Yes. This is a common way to design multithreaded servers and accepted design practice.

Comment: So it's impossible in TCP unless you're using NGINX with the SO_REUSEPORT option, which until about five minutes ago was only for UDP, and none which is mentioned in your question.

Comment: @Nemo I think that was only made available in NGINX itself a couple years ago (http://developers-club.com/posts/259403/), in version 1.9.1 (2015-05-26).

Comment: @DevNull It's a kernel feature that has nothing to do with nginx per se. nginx just happens to use it and document the performance advantages. This answer is misleading, useless, and wrong.

Comment: @Nemo Five words of it don't apply to NGINX since 2015. The rest of it is correct. It seems to me that the NGINX people would be better off improving their spin locks rather than changing 35-year-old semantics.

Comment: @EJP - "starts a new thread per accepted socket" - please don't suggest this horrible design to the younglings. Consider it's security flaws. I can already imagine the server crashing down under the weight of all the context switches... add to that the ~2Mb overhead per thread (for stack allocation) and this resource hungry monster you're feeding feels so terribly menacing...

Comment: @Myst Oh come off it. That's how all beginners start writing servers. Yes there are other architectures, but here're plenty of production servers out there, by why I mean millions, that do exactly this.

Comment: @EJP I know there's a bunch of servers out there that do the exact same thing (in production no less), which is exactly why I think it's so important to stop this trend. The thread-per-connection design is too fragile and inefficient to be considered the norm.

Comment: @Myst Good luck with stopping this 'trend'. This architecture is sufficient for nine out of ten servers.